# Create DateTime from date string and time string

Tags: php, datetime

I have a form that submits both a date and a time, and I wish to create one \DateTime object based on these values

The `$submission['time']` value looks like: 'T09:45:00'

The `$submission['date']` value looks like: '2016-07-11'

I've tried

```
var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'Y-m-d TH:i:s', $reportArray['date'] . ' ' . $reportArray['time'])
); // also tried without 'T' (TH:i:s)
```

However this broke the script.

Is there a simple way to create one \DateTime object from one date string and one time string?

Comment: I guess the 'T' at the beginning of the time string is the problem. Does it ever change? What does it do?

Comment: I think it indicates daylight saving time @KIKOSoftware, actually I don't think that's right.

Comment: Yes, the `T` in the format represents a time zone, not a 'T'. You could try this format: `'Y-m-d \TH:i:s'`. The backslash escapes the 'T' to a literal 'T'. Oh, and you really do not need to add in the space.

Comment: Ah, that works perfectly, I'll pop what I ended up with as answer @KIKOSoftware, cheers for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'T' you have used in the format represents a time zone, not a literal 'T'. You could use this format: `'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'`. The backslash escapes the 'T' to a literal 'T'. I left out the space, because you don't need it. Like this:

```
var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $reportArray['date'] . $reportArray['time'])
);
```

This answer does, of course, assume that the 'T' is always there and never changes.

Comment: No need to use `createFromFormat()` with this kind of input; it is perfectly valid input, so just use `new DateTime()`: [demo](https://eval.in/603415).

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
<?php
$d1=$submission['date']='2016-07-11';
$t1=$submission['time']='T09:45:00';
$con=$d1.$t1;
$displaytime=date('d-m-Y H:i:s A',strtotime($con));
echo $displaytime;
?>
```

It will gives an output like:**11-07-2016 09:45:00 AM** which you wanted.